# JSON - Selecting a value using operators?

Tags: sql, azure

So I'm working with a dataset that looks like below:
Query:

```
Select Key, NativeObject
FROM dbo.UserResource
```

Sample Result:

```
Key    | NativeObject
1121   |{   "NativeID": "3452",   "AccountType": "Active",   "AdNumber": "",   "AdditionalDimensions": "",   "UserDescription": "User", "IsDeleted": "0" }
```

A few scenarios I'm encountering issues are:

1. I want to pull the keys where AdNumber is not null
2. I want to pull the NativeIDs where value is greater than X number ie) NativeID >= 3000

Currently, I'm working with adding this to the Select clause, but I can't figure out how to add parameters like above. Any help would be appreciated!

```
json_value('{"IsDeleted": "1"}', '$.IsDeleted') as 'Output'
```

Comment: Have you read this? https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4138/advanced-json-techniques-in-sql-server-part-3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a table and inserted values into that using below code:

```
CREATE TABLE UserResources( KeyId INT ,NativeObject 
NVARCHAR(4000)CONSTRAINT PK_Car PRIMARY KEY(keyID),
CONSTRAINT IsValidJSON1 CHECK (ISJSON(NativeObject) = 1));


insert into UserResources(KeyId,NativeObject) VALUES(4,'{"NativeID": "3452",   "AccountType": "Active",   "AdNumber": "",   "AdditionalDimensions": [{"right":1}],   "UserDescription": "User", "IsDeleted": "0" }'),
(2,'{"NativeID": "3452",   "AccountType": "Active",   "AdNumber": "",   "AdditionalDimensions": [{"left":2}],   "UserDescription": "User", "IsDeleted": "1" }'),
(3,'{"NativeID": "3452",   "AccountType": "Active",   "AdNumber": "",   "AdditionalDimensions": [{"left":3}],   "UserDescription": "User", "IsDeleted": "0" }');
```

I selected values from JSON column using below code:

```
SELECT KeyId, NativeObject = JSON_QUERY(NativeObject, '$.AdditionalDimensions')
  FROM dbo.UserResources;
```

I got below result:

[image]

In this way you can select values of JSON.